# Selecting multiple records and passing them on

Tags: php, mysql

calling up a method to load a userstatus from DB.

```
public function loadStatus($id)
{
    $stmt = $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM messages  WHERE user = '$id'  ");

    if($stmt -> num_rows > 0 )
    {
```

Here Im also returning  the result as an array(this also works, but I only get the last entry). Im kind of stuck , Im just unable to get the Foreach or While loop right here

```
return $stmt -> fetch_array();


    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: which MVC you are using ...CI?

Comment: If that's a wrapper around [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), yeah, that only returns a single row. You could go for [`mysqli_fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php). If it's not a wrapper around that, please provide more info about the database interface you are using.

Comment: @Riad codeigniter has **nothing** to do with MVC architectural pattern.

Comment: @teresko thanks, but this is only a private project with for training purposes. Secondly I do validate the form fields , so I dont think an SQl injection will succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at last I found the solution:

```
public function loadStatus($id)
{
$stmt = $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM messages  WHERE user = '$id'  ");

if($stmt -> num_rows > 0 )
{

$a = array();
while($row = $stmt -> fetch_assoc)){
    array_push($a, $row);
}
return $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put like this:

```
return $stmt->result();
```

as `fetch_array()` will return one fetched row.